# pass attribute on click link instead hash

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a link in my menu. It has an attributte like `title=.roc`.
When I click on this link, I want to save this attribute and click on element with the same attribute on the destination page.

Page `example.com`. I click in the next link.

```
<li class="menu-item"><a title=".roc" href="https://example.com/port/#flash">Roc</a></li>
```

So now, in *example.com/port/*, it should click the element with `title=".roc"`:

```
<a id="flash" href="#" title=".roc">ROC2</a>
```

I have this code, but I dont know how pass the attribute instead the hash:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var activeTab = document.querySelector(location.hash);
  history.replaceState(null, null, ' ');
  window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    if (activeTab) {
      setTimeout(function(){ activeTab.click(); }, 100);
    }  
  })
});
```

Comment: `activeTab = location.hash==='#flash' ? $('[title]=".roc"') : $(location.hash)`?  Also why are you binding the load event in your DOM ready hook?  If you want ot pass parameters other than just hash, you should use query parameters.  URLSearchParams can build it for you

Comment: I dont want the parameters in the url. The load its because I should wait to load the full page to make the click. If its too fast wont work (If I dont use the load).

Comment: you can use sessionStorage and localStorage to persist data.  if cross domain the only way to communicate values is to use query params or have a server-side api that stores and returns data.  it's not clear what you're trying to achieve, but those are the ways to pass data across pages

Comment: @user120242 Its just the same domain, not cross domain. Thx

Comment: so I'm still not sure what exactly your use case is, but if you want to just save some data that the other page can also access, you can use sessionStorage.setItem('title','.roc')  and then sesionStorage.getItem('title') on the next page to retrieve .roc

Comment: Yes. I want click in a link with attribute. Then when the linked page appear It make a click on the attribute stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the pages you want to hook transfer 'title' from:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  $(document.body).on('click','a[title]', function(event) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('title', event.target.getAttribute('title'));
  });
});
```

then on the other page:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
  var activeTab = document.querySelector(`[title="${sessionStorage.getItem('title')}"]`);
  window.addEventListener('load', function (event) {
    if (activeTab) {
      setTimeout(function(){ activeTab.click(); }, 100);
    }  
  })
});
```

Comment: You want all links with title attribute to do that?

Comment: Sorry, ur code is working well.  If i am in example.com and I click in your link all its fine. But if i am in the destination url and i click in your link, the browser will reload the page and after It make the click with the attibute. (I dont want the reload when i am in the destination page)

Comment: that is because the code hooks page load to execute that code on page load.  when do you want it to try to click activeTab?

Comment: Sorry, Its my fault again. If i am in example.com/port/ and i click a link to example.com/port/ browser will reload. Sorry do you have any idea to avoid this?

Comment: you have to hook click and event.preventDefault() to prevent default behavior

Comment: I dont know how to event.preventDefault() but I can just delete the href in the link if the url has "example.com/port/"